# Upload text as file to another server with PHP

Tags: php, api, file-upload

I'm working with a 3rd party API that allows me to upload a file to its database. This file has an specific format, but it's plain text.

What I want to do, is generate the text by myself with a PHP script on my own site and upload it to it's server like a file.

The catch is: I want to do this without have to save a temporary file on my own server and if possible, avoiding the use of cURL.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Then do so. What's your problem?

Answer (score 2):

```
file_put_contents('http://...', $your_text_file);
```

However, if the API has http basic auth on it, you'll ned to us a [stream context](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php) to set all that up.